# XCODE: Error reading plist: stream had too few bytes

Tags: iphone, xcode, testing, plist

Ive developed an app for iPhone. Ive successfully tested it in the iPhone Simulator, but as soon as I run it on my test iDevice, it throws an error:

Error reading plist: stream had too few bytes, format: 1064028076

How could it have an error if it works correctly on the sim?

```
2012-03-23 10:40:16.791 Ask Alarm[5697:707] Error reading plist: stream had too few bytes,
format: 1064028076
2012-03-23 10:40:16.807 Ask Alarm[5697:707] 2012-03-23 17:40:16 +0000
2012-03-23 10:40:16.814 Ask Alarm[5697:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSCFString stringByAppendingString:]: nil
argument'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x32b818bf 0x358491e5 0x32b817b9 0x32b817db 0x3216b121 0x697dd 0x36ba57ff 0x36c063b9 0x36c06357 0x36c05c91 0x36c08661 0x36c081a7 0x36bae6b5 0x36c0961b 0x36c4f691 0x36c4e14f 0x3028e93 0x36ca8d97 0x32adb435 0x36b879eb 0x36b879a7 0x36b87985 0x36b876f5 0x36b8802d 0x36b8650f 0x36b85f01 0x36b6c4ed 0x36b6bd2d 0x337f0df3 0x32b55553 0x32b554f5 0x32b54343 0x32ad74dd 0x32ad73a5 0x337effcd 0x36b9a743 0x670ab 0x669a8)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

Comment: What is your code for loading the plist?

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED!
apparently everything case sensitive on the iDevice. I fail at life.

Comment: Haha if you think every little error like this means you fail at life then I must be a colossal failure! ;-)

Comment: Lol well I just spent 2 hours trying to fix something that was caused by a single capital letter so.... tie!

Comment: Ah, yeah that is the worst.  I've learned that if I've banged my head over something for more than about 20 minutes, I just need to walk away and think about something else for a bit.  Much of the time, when I return I immediately see the problem and slap myself for having overlooked something so obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's either a mis-formatted plist file or something is bogus in your `stringByAppendingString` call.

Check both for anything obvious and if you don't see it, modify your question to add a bit of the code (both the plist and the code that includes the `stringByAppendingString` line)